# How to display "yes" or "no" message box in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

**I want to display a message to the user to select yes or no**. According to the clicked button(Yes or no), the **value should be passed to a query as a parameter**. How can I do this. This is what I have done so far.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function confirm()
        {
            var confirmValue = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirmValue.type = "hidden";
            confirmValue.name = "confirmValue";

            if (confirm("Do you want to finalize? If you click yes, you will not be able to update  and application will be passed to the MBD Coordinator")) {
                confirmValue.value = "YES";
            }
            else
            {
                confirmValue.value = "NO";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirmValue);
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" Text="Finish" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#9B0423" 
                        Font-Bold="true" Width="100px" Height="30px" ForeColor="#9B0423" Style="margin-right:20px;" OnClick="btnFinish_Click" OnClientClick = "confirm()"/>
```

This is the C# code

```
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirmValue"];
if (confirmValue == "Yes")
{
      string value = "YES";
}
else
{
      string value = "NO";
}
```

**But in this I don't get a message to select any option.**

Comment: you've overridden `window.confirm` with your function `confirm` and within this function you call `confirm` ... recursion is your issue ... call your function `Confirm` or something else ... also note that the `window.confirm` function offers the choices `OK/Cancel` not `Yes/No`

Comment: If you want a Yes/No box use a library like `alertify`

Comment: @JaromandaX, It worked thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the function from "confirm" to something else. You are overriding the default confirm function in JavaScript.